# How to create an executable in maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a compiler project. What I am suppose to do is, I have to generate an executable called "ctop" using maven. By using that executable I have to be able to do "ctop cfile pfile" which will generate an assembly file called "pfile" from a program in c called "cfile". As I have never used maven before I have no idea how to do that. I'm using eclipse IDE and I have created maven project as well. But I have no idea how to work with maven. I have a main file located at (/src/main/java/me/name/project_compiler/Main.java). I have to be able to execute this and other mains.

My pom.xml file looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>me.name</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>project-compiler</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the appassembler plugin

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/

Comment: what should I do using that plugin? can u help me please

Comment: Sorry would you please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The best teacher to this question is the following article, assume that you have basic maven knowledge: [Maven-Assembly-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

Next is a simple example:

**1. configure the assembly plugin to ur pom.xml, that means add the assembly plugin config to the pom's build/plugins module. for u, add the below code after dependencies, don't forget to change the mainClass.**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>urpackage.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**2. edit the assembly.xml file, the field such as project.build.directory is maven self-supported**

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
        <id>bin</id>
        <formats>
            <!--u have many other choices-->
            <format>tar.bz2</format>
            <format>zip</format>
        </formats>
        <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
        <fileSets>
            <!--put fileSet config to include or exclude files in ur final package-->
            <fileSet>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
    </assembly>
```

**3. run: mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true, then you will get what you want in your target directory, just unpackage&check it**

Comment: thanks for your reply. but where can I find assembly.xml file?

Comment: you need to create a new file named assembly.xml and put this file at the same directory with the pom.xml. In fact you can put this file anywhere you want only if have the right configuration in ur pom (<descriptor>/xxx/xx/xxx/assembly.xml</descriptor>)